# Cordova media capture can take photos but not video

Tags: javascript, cordova

I can use the cordova-plugin-media-capture plugin to take a photo, but fail with a simple error code `20` when I try to use the video. I am on the browser so I don't think it's one of those intent things.

```js
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(
                result => {
                    var i, path, len;
                    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
                        // do something interesting with the file
                    }
                    resolve(result);
                },
                error => {
                    console.error('Video failed: ' + error);
                    reject('Failed to take a video');
                },
                {
                    limit: 1
                }
            )
```

I really don't know what else to say. I don't know what the code means, it doesn't seem possible to find out.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/index.html